# vectors in a list - how to extract element from one of the vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

I want to extract the 3rd element of the second vector of the first
sub-list.....
This is the list of vectors

```
A <- letters[1:4]
B <- letters[5:10]
C <- letters[11:15]
D <- c(1:10)
E <- c(20:5)

Z <- list(x = c(A,B,C), y = c(D, E))
```

which returns

```
>Z
$x
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o"

$y
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5
```

I've tried this

```
Z[[1]][B[3]]
```

but it returns

```
[1] NA
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to differentiate between `A`, `B` and `C` when you use them in a vector (`c(A, B, C)`). I think the elements in `x` and `y` should be in a list :

```
Z <- list(x = list(A,B,C), y = list(D, E))
```

If you have that we can do :

```
Z[[1]][[2]][3]
#[1] "g"
```

This will return 3rd element of the second vector of the first sub-list.

Answer (score 0):

On lists, you have these two options, for example, extract the second value, of the first element of your list. The first system is only valid, when you give names to the elements of your list.

```
Z$x[2]


Z[[1]][2]
```